# Java MySQL transaction and executeBatch

Tags: java, mysql, transactions

I have met a problem that I am unable to figure out.

I have the following SQL code snippet, where I insert multiple rows into a table. It is important that no rows are added on an exception.

The code works as intended, but if the rollback part is removed, some rows are added on an exception, even though connection.commit(); is never invoked. Why is that?

My concern is: What happens if my application is killed by the operating system while invoking a batch insert, and thereby the rollback part is never called. My tests shows that nothing is inserted in that case. But I'm am still stumbled on why some rows are inserted on an exception, if the rollback part is removed.

Any hints on this?

```
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        connection = DBConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection(JDNI);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_PREFIX + TABLE_OUTBOX + "...");

        // add multiple statements

        stmt.executeBatch();

        connection.commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            log.debug(ex);
            log.debug("rolling back insert message batch");
            connection.rollback();
            log.debug("rollback success");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.debug("unable to rollback", e);
        }
        throw new TranquilityException("could not insert endpoints!!", ex);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.warn("Could not close sql statement", ex);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.setAutoCommit(true);
                connection.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Could not close sql connection", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your sql tables in Innodb storage engine? MyISAM don't support transactions.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but are you sure the records were persisted even after the connection was closed when the commit method was not called due to exception? That seems to be too fundamental a problem to occur!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons I can see for this to happen:

- The first is that it appears you are using a connection pool. In this
  case, your connections are re-used. If you return a connection with
  an uncommitted transaction to the pool and that connection is checked out by
  another method at a later point, the transaction could be getting committed
  when that later method is committed.
- The second (and more likely) is that in your finally block, you are
  setting connection.setAutoCommit(true); When your method completes,
  that will cause everything in your connection to be flushed. I know
  you need to do this for the connection pool, but you should make sure
  your connection is in a completed state before doing this.

Comment: Yes, I am using a connection pool. Both reasons are very likely. I did some further research. When I remove connection.close() in the final block, nothing seems to be inserted on an exception. If I remove connection.setAutoCommit(true), some rows are inserted on an exception. Based on the previous answers. Can I assume that another database interaction, using the same connection from the connectionpool, flushes the inserts that have not been comitted?

Comment: Yes, that would be my best guess and consistent with experiences I have had in the past. I am not familiar with the specifics of the connection pool, but I would assume that by not calling connection.close(), the connection is not being returned to the pool preventing other sessions from flushing the changes.